# How do I implement a multi-line flexbox?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

Despite my Googling, I've found few examples on how to implement multiple line flexboxes. None of the code I've gotten from examples has worked. I have three elements inside a flexbox and I want the first to be on top and the second and third to be on the bottom row.

```
<div class="flexbox">
  <div id="element1">element 1</div>
  <div id="element2">element 2</div>
  <div id="element3">element 3</div>
</div>
```

I've tried using these properties:

```css
.flexbox {
  width: 300px;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  box-lines: multiple;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#element1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

and giving it a set width but it still won't wrap, even if the first element has a width of 100%. Am I missing certain vendor prefixes or is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Be aware that firefox currently (25) does not supports multi-line flexbox flexbox layouts, due to a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=702508).

Comment: Here you go! http://codepen.io/klamping/pen/waMOeX

Comment: See also https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The flex box spec has [changed](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) in the last few months and you are using the old syntax. The new spec I believe is only currently implemented only in Chrome Canary and to some extent in latest chrome. (It's a little buggy)   box-lines multiple is gone so to achieve this vertical layout there are a few ways. Using -webkit-flex-direction:column; so

```
<div id="flexbox">
    <div class="box">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="box">DIV 2</div>
    <div class="box">DIV 3</div>
</div>
```

and css :

```
#flexbox {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
}

#flexbox .box {
    -webkit-flex: 1;

}
```

Using wrapping:

```
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
```

and setting your direction to:

```
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
```

So

```
<div id="flexbox">
    <div class="box">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="box">DIV 2</div>
    <div class="box">DIV 3</div>
    <div class="box">DIV 4</div>
    <div class="box bigger">DIV 5</div>
    <div class="box">DIV 6</div>
</div>

#flexbox {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
    }

#flexbox .box {

    -webkit-flex: 130px 1;

    }

#flexbox .box.bigger {

    -webkit-flex: 330px 1;

    }
```

There's a whole bunch of examples on the spec page linked above.

Comment: You can now directly use the `flex` value without any prefix, which is supported by most browsers now.

Comment: Seems like `flex-wrap: wrap` should more explicitly be part of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `flex-direction` attribute.

```
.container {
  flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse;
}
```

Refer to the following article:
[http://fend-tricks.com/flexbox-intro/](https://web.archive.org/web/20171214034957/http://fend-tricks.com/flexbox-intro/)

Comment: This webpage has been deactivated.

Comment: @FranzHolzinger Hi, thanks for pointing that out. I've replaced it with its last Wayback Machine snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** you're probably looking for `flex-wrap: wrap`

Then you might be interested in:

- `justify-content` - spacing around / between the items
- `flex-direction` - change the way the items flow (row, column, reverse, etc)

But then you might have a problem where the items in the last row don't [layout correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid). So you'll give up on `flex`, and use `display: grid` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491643/1026023), something like:

```css
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
justify-content: space-between;
grid-gap: 20px;
```

Which is only very [slightly less supported](https://caniuse.com/css-grid) than [flex is](https://caniuse.com/flexbox).