# Centering a variable width grid while aligning its elements to the left

Tags: html, css, alignment

Consider the following

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="grid">
         <div class="unit"></div>
         <div class="unit"></div>
         <div class="unit"></div>
         <div class="unit"></div>
         <div class="unit"></div>
         <div class="unit"></div>
          ....
      </div>
</div>
```

Using images, basically what I have is something like this

[image]

As you can see the green blocks and the container are aligned to the left

What I want to acheive is something like this.

[image]

The `.unit` elements have constant width

The `.grid` element should expand with width (so that more `unit` elements would fit into 1 line) while being always centered within `.container`.

Any clue how to achieve that using only CSS (and maybe some html wrappers if necessary) ?

Comment: Without seeing the css it's hard to say. This is being caused by your floats. When you are using floats, there is no easy way to center the children in the parent container. If the container is a fixed width, you may be able to add `margin: 0 auto;` to it so the container itself is centered.

Comment: I'm not doing any floats .. margin wont work because If I set `grid` to `block` there is no way to center the `units` as in the image

Answer (score 1):

Let me begin by saying that this is an interesting question and my first thought was that flexbox is the way to solve this.  I have tried all manner of flexbox arrangements, but this type of solution eluded me.  So, below is the solution that uses floating, clearing, and media queries.

For this example, I have assumed that each row would have at least 3 and no more than 9 boxes.  However, you can extend this solution to handle anywhere between 1 and more than 9 boxes.

Here's HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Here's a CSS that (1) performs a mini-reset to eliminate browser-applied paddings and margins that may interfere with sizing and (2) formats the `.grid` and its `div` children:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid {
    display: table;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    min-width: 330px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 61px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: teal;
    float: left;
}
```

The `.container` block was eliminated because `.grid` is displayed as a table.  The latter is a block that shrinkwraps around its children and `margin: 0 auto` can be applied to center it on the page.  The `.grid`'s `min-width` of 330px assures that a minimum of three blocks can fit per line.  Whenever floating happens within a `table` element, its margins do not collapse, therefore no explicit clearing of floats (e.g., via clearfix) is necessary.

Each `.grid` `div` child takes 110px of horizontal space (100px width + 10px in left and right margins).  This number is important for the media queries code that follows below:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 330px) and (max-width: 439px) {
    .grid > div:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 440px) and (max-width: 549px) {
    .grid > div:nth-of-type(4n + 1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 659px) {
    .grid > div:nth-of-type(5n + 1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 660px) and (max-width: 769px) {
    .grid > div:nth-of-type(6n + 1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 770px) and (max-width: 879px) {
    .grid > div:nth-of-type(7n + 1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 880px) and (max-width: 989px) {
    .grid > div:nth-of-type(8n + 1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 990px) {
    .grid > div:nth-of-type(9n + 1) {
        clear: left;
    }    
}
```

The rationale behind the code is this: if there is enough space to include only n blocks per line, then every (n + 1)th block's left edge is cleared, which moves the block to a new line.

And, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hWXw/.  Resize the preview window to see the adjustments.

Comment: This actually solve the issue, but the problem is its not generic. Imagine I have like 20 blocks in 1 row, or more, being conditional on the screen width is something I don't want to rely on

Comment: We all have to work within certain limitations.  Given the specifics of your request - CSS-only solution that centers a `.grid` that stretches just enough, within its container, to perfectly shrinkwrap fixed-sized blocks that flow to the left - that's the best I could come up with.  Cheers.

Comment: And, here's a product of my conversation with @Tyblitz - a generalizable solution that uses jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/GWQSe/.

Comment: Seems that it is doable without the need of jquery, just by adding trailing empty elements

Comment: The size of the `.unit` and the width of the user's browser will affect how many trailing empty elements you will need.  That will definitely require some good 'ole code.  And, this is hardly an optimal solution because if, say, for one screen size you'll need 5 trailing blocks, then for a resized browser some of those trailing elements would need to be removed.  More code.  Overall, using spacer elements reminds of the days of spacer gifs.  That's not the most elegant way to do things.  Using pure CSS with media queries sounds a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, make sure:
1. In the `.grid` rule, `text-align` is set to `center`
2. In the `.unit` rule, `display` is set to `inline-block`. The `div` element is a block-level element and so each new element is displayed on a new line. Giving the `display` property a value of `inline-block` forces all the `div`s with class `unit` to be displayed on the same line (until there's no more space). Also `text-align : center` doesn't work with elements with display property set to `block`, and block-level elements have a display value of `block` by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just give value to your classes like this,

```
.grid { text-align:center; }

.unit { display:inline-block; }
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

If not, than please show your full code via Jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

@DRD's answer is nice but requires lots of media queries. If the following floats your boat however: don't look too far when it can be simple: set a padding-left/-right on your container...

```
.grid {
  padding: 0 5%;
}
```

You'll notice the whitespace is not even when the width isn't a multiplication of the `.unit` 's entire box (padding, margin, border, width). Setting a %-based width can help here.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/5hWXw/2/) for a test case. I've added a tiny bit of Javascript to adjust the padding dynamically, remove it to see the CSS-only result. **EDIT:** @DRD created a jQuery function which works better than my JS, see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GWQSe/) (don't forget to include jQuery if you want to use it).

Comment: I'd love to see a fiddle of this solution.

Comment: @DRD, I forked your fiddle and added it to my answer, good point.

Comment: Using JS to adjust the padding is one way to do, but it also creates a lot of flickering.  Here's a solution that let's the browser do all the positioning and the script decides to which elements the `clear: left` is applied.  The experience is much smoother and the solution is generalizable without any need to use media queries: http://jsfiddle.net/GWQSe/.  Also, it uses less processing power even though I am using jQuery instead of talking to DOM directly.

Comment: @DRD Great fix, I'll add it to my answer! The flickering only occurs when downsizing the window (?), I didn't take the time to correct that in regular JS. Makin' this work in native JS would be the cherry on the cake. Although if the function is only triggered on page load (users don't go around resizing windows all the time, though they occasionally might), both work fine. Thanks a lot for your addition.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a solution to this is similar to that in here [Flex-box: Align last row to grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid)

First of all setting `.grid` to `inline`, then adding more div's with `height: 0` would do the trick, number of extra div's should be atleast equal to max-number of `units` in 1 line (minus 1).

This is a bit incontinent, but still easier than defining multiple `@media` as @DRD suggested, and doesn't require javascript/window.resize() handling

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="unit"></div>
        <div class="unit"></div>
        <div class="unit"></div>
        <div class="unit"></div>
        <div class="unit"></div>
        <div class="unit"></div>
        <div class="unit empty"></div>
        <div class="unit empty"></div>
        <div class="unit empty"></div>
        <div class="unit empty"></div>
        <div class="unit empty"></div>
        <div class="unit empty"></div>
        <div class="unit empty"></div>
    </div>
</div>


.container {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
}

.empty {
   height: 0 !important;
}

.grid {
   display: inline;
}
```

I still hope for a better solution using only css

Comment: The codepen referred to in the post that you have linked to uses flexbox arrangement where boxes' dimensions change depending on the browser width: http://jsfiddle.net/4z8b4/.  The minute you fix their width, the solution falls apart: http://jsfiddle.net/nkX6p/.

Comment: One more thing and I am done with this thread.  CSS is still a presentational language, so pick your battles, dude.  I predict that in the future many more things that we do in JS we'll do easily in CSS.