# CSS flex last incomplete row items take the width of complete row items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I'm creating a flexbox; a container has a `max-width`, say `max-width = 500px`, and child items each has `min-width: 130px` and `flex-grow: 1` to fill the whole row space.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7wroxkhj/6/

What I want to achieve is, for the last row items to take the same width of preceding items. i.e.: item #7 and item #8 to have the same width of items from 1 to 6.

How can I achieve that?

**UPDATE:**

JS solutions are welcomed!

Comment: if the container has a fixed width, why not use a fixed width for this children?

Comment: Actually, the container has `max-width` not `width`, so it's not actually fixed width.

Comment: And why are you hiding this detail?

Comment: It was a mistake. Again, it's `max-width` not `width`, updated my question.

Comment: Is there a specific number of flex items, or is it variable?

Comment: variable; results from db

Comment: Duplicate of [CSS Flexbox: Make All Items same Size without Clipping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34402753/1529630)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider something along the lines of invisible flex items at the end of the list.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child hidden">9</div>  /* new */
    <div class="child hidden">10</div> /* new */
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/7wroxkhj/9/)

Comment: This would work well only with expected number of items.

Comment: Actually, this solution doesn't depend on the number of items. Try adding and removing divs in the demo (always keeping hidden divs last).

Comment: This solution exploits the `max-width` of the container, and the `min-width` of each item, which results in a predictable number of items in each row.

Comment: The only thing you may want to consider is releasing the fixed `height` of the container, possibly making it a `min-height`, so it could expand with additional items, or giving it `overflow: auto`, to generate a scrollbar.

Comment: Just tested everything again. Seems to work perfectly (except for the container height issue, which depends on your preference). If I'm misinterpreting or missing something just let me know.

Comment: No. Using dummy child elements solved it. Didn't have to use the hidden class though.

Answer (score 0):

Give top the pseudo element the same properties that you are giving the elements, but a height very low.

But if more than 2 pseudo element are needed, you need another technique

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.parent::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 130px 1;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 10px;
}
.child {
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 130px 1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

Note that the real height for the pseudo would be 0px, and the background yellow wouldn't be there...

Those are just for demo purposes

Edit: FF handles different the situation where the minimun height comes from min-height and the situation where it comes from flex-basis. But Chrome handles those just the same. So my previous solution worked only for Chrome. (Don't know for sure which is "standard".

I changed the min-height of .child and moved it to flex-basis, now it works ok both in Chrome and FF.

Comment: It makes no difference at all. See how it looks: http://imgur.com/YyanRML

Answer (score -2):

## UPDATE

Ok, I finally figured out why OPs was seeing everything so differently than I was. I was using Chrome and OP was using Firefox. The following is the newest demo that should be compatible with Chrome and Firefox.

- The major changes include wrapping the whole layout in a flex-column container.
- Removed the `margins: 10px;` because flexbox with `box-sizing` doesn't handle margins or borders as expected.
- Used a plethora of min and max height and width properties.
- Used `justify-content: space-between` and `align-items: space-between` on column and row directions which made a tight yet flexible grid.

https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/fkczpggy/

```css
.case {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: space-around;
  margin: auto 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.parent {
  background: red;
  height: 99vh;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: space-between;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  min-width: 130px;
  min-height: 130px;
  border: 1% solid transparent;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  margin: 1%;
}

.child:last-of-type {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <section class="case">
  <div class="parent">
<div class="child">1</div>
<div class="child">2</div>
<div class="child">3</div>
<div class="child">4</div>
<div class="child">5</div>
<div class="child">6</div>
<div class="child">7</div>
<div class="child">8</div>
<div class="child">9</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

**OLD**

---

Here's a lazy but effective way:

**Updated to reflect dynamic variable number of divs**

Use **`nth-of-type(n+9)`**
or this would be better:
**`last-of-type`**

1. Add the 9th div
2. Then add this single line to your CSS:

   ```
   .child:nth-of-type(n+9) {
     visibility: hidden;
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   .child:last-of-type {
     visibility: hidden;
   }
   ```

https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/4fp88arh/

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
/*.parent:after {
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1000000000;
}*/

.child {
  background: blue;
  min-width: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

/*.child:nth-of-type(n+9) {
  visibility: hidden;
}*/

 .child:last-of-type {
   visibility: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? My answer is just as valid as Michael_D's .

Comment: How's it valid? This is the result: http://imgur.com/YyanRML

Comment: Did you take a look at my demos, because this is what I see:http://imgur.com/a/xwps3

Comment: @user1181378 Ok, I know what's going on, I'm using Chrome and you must be using Firefox. Ok I have done some cross browser testing and I believe this will work. Please see update.