# I do not know why Flexbox items stretch

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox, but I don't know the items stretch.
I would like to obtain this result:

[image]

The content items are justified and they wrap when the space of the content ends. Like this:

[image]

Items are DIV that contains labels and input elements. So I want that the whole dive wrap and the labels are not separated by the inputs.

Here the HTML:

```
<tr class="form_boxes">
    <td colspan="3">
        <div class="">
            <span class="">NPA</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="np.npa" maxlength="5" class="char_5" />
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <span>NXX</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="np.nxx" />
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <span>ISO</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="np.iso" maxlength="5" class="char_5" />
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <span>Descrizione</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="np.descrizione" />
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <span>Location</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="np.location" />
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <span>Root</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="np.root" />
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <span>Billing ID</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="np.billingId" />
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <span class="no-wrap">Ultimo aggiornamento: {{ np.ultimoUpdate }}</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and here the CSS:

```
#internal_content .form_boxes { 
    width:500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
    align-content: flex-start;

    }

#internal_content .form_boxes td {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I also would like to remove the fixed size of the TR...
This is the result I obtain:

[image]

As you can see, the TR size is ok... and the TD size so (trust me please). The problem is that also the DIVs stretch, but I do not know why!

[image]

Can anyone helps me to reach my purpose please?

**UPDATE**

With your solutions, now I obtain this:

[image]

Also the last line is justified... It should be like the first image I posted instead.. Do I have to create a new parent flex box?

Comment: Apply the `display: flex` to the `td` instead

Comment: If you're gonna use flexbox there's really no need to use a table too!

Comment: I updated the question and yes... I removed table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your flexbox on the parent of the divs so the td, your class should be on the td element so the divs are affected

```
#internal_content .form_boxes td { 
    width:500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
    align-content: flex-start;
}
```

and remove the width that should do it

Also the divs stretch because they are block elements and block elements by default always have full width unless you declare it otherwise

and this was also part of the solution for the question

[Flex-box: Align last row to grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid)

Comment: @Ciccio is it neccesary for it to have width 500px? Because I think it doesnt have the space for it to fit all of it in two rows

Comment: I removed the width:500px... however, the problem is not the number of rows, but the las line is justified too.. I would like it stops on the left... I do not know if I explained good.. I mean "ultimo aggiornamento", should be near the tectbox of the billing id... not at the end of the line

Comment: Add a parent to the last elements that you want to the left

Comment: I have added... but nothing changed... do I have to add some style too?

Comment: Can you update the html code in the question or put it up in jsfiddle? So I can  try

Comment: I have solved with this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid