# How to center `layout="row"` div?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a grid made up by cards from the angular material. The problem is: the cards have fixed size, and immediately after the wrapping there is a space on the right. I want to eliminate it, by centering the `md-content`. But it has the width of the row, so I can't make any centering properly. How can I fix it (i.e. make the width of the `md-content` equal to actual content width)? Thank you.

```
<md-content layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <md-card ng-repeat="channel in $ctrl.channels" ui-sref="" md-ink-ripple>
    <div layout-align="center" layout='row' style="width: 160px; height: 160px">
      <img ng-src="{{channel.logo_url}}" alt="{{channel.name}}" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <footer style="padding: 2px;" layout-align="center">
      <h3>{{channel.name}}</h3>
    </footer>
  </md-card>
</md-content>
```

Comment: try `display: inline-block`

Comment: that makes the element that has the property as big as its contents, for reference

Comment: @vladdobra Did try this, with just inline containers like `span` too, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the margin of the content to adjust its position

Comment: That wouldn't be centering, just offsetting. Doesn't solve the problem, more than this, make the content area smaller.

Comment: Yes I see. I have not well anderstand the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you add `layout-align="center"` to the `md-content` it will centre the content - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/wzVdjg?editors=1010#0)

Note, however, that if the bottom row has "less" cards they are centred too, which may not be what you want.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content layout="row" layout-wrap layout-align="center">
    <md-card ng-repeat="channel in ctrl.channels" ui-sref="" md-ink-ripple>
      <div layout-align="center" layout='row' style="width: 160px; height: 160px">
        <img ng-src="{{channel.logo_url}}" alt="{{channel.name}}" style="width: 100%;" />
      </div>
      <footer style="padding: 2px;" layout-align="center">
        <h3>{{channel.name}}</h3>
      </footer>
    </md-card>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
  this.channels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
});
```

Comment: "Note, however, that if the bottom row has "less" cards they are centred too, which may not be what you want." - yeah, unfortunately. It looks like the problem is with the layout-wrap, more specifically with the state after the wrap, because the container is content-wise wide, before wrapping, after - it is 100%.

This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34816625/4753661 could be useful here, though the grid isn't centered well at the last row either :(

Comment: @Georgy If your divs have a fixed width you may want to use Grid List - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList

Comment: Isn't it for the responsive tiles? They specify colspan, rowspan and ratio, not width and height, as far as I understand.