# How do I justify-content:flex-start on the next line of a wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I've been doing a lot of research and I can't seem to figure the solution I need and I was wondering if someone had the same problem. I've attached a sample of the code.

Basically, How do I get it to `justify-content: flex-start` on the next line of the wrap? (If that makes sense)

The page would then be responsive to any size of the browser.

```
<head>
<style>
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.c
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.c_style
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    margin: 0px 40px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div{
    margin:0px;
}
</style>
</head>    
<body>
<div>
<ul class="c_style">
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
    <li><div class="c"></div></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more what result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok great, I'm trying to get both lines to line up exactly when they start to wrap, right now space-between gives a great result on the first line, but once it start wrapping, it doesn't look that great on the second line. So I thought maybe there was an :after for a wrap or linebreak. But I can't find one.

Comment: Your only option is: keep `space-between` and use `javascript` on `load` and `resize` events, to count the number of elements on last row and add the correct number of items to markup so the first ones on last row display correctly. You'll need to wipe empty elements on `resize` and debounce adding new ones until `resize` finishes.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu - You just went straight over my head, hehe. I'm guessing you saying to count the elements then pass that number into Java?

Comment: I'm saying there's no way to do this with `CSS` alone. You'll need a `javascript` function that will check your layout and *"make it right"*. You need to run this function on two events: `window.load` and `window.resize`. Because `window.resize` can fire up to 100 times per second during a resize of a browser window, you want to limit the times your *"make it right"* function can run/second, by debouncing it. That's the only way to achieve what you want. And `Java != JavaScript`

Comment: Ok, I managed to find the css I needed via one of the links on the suggestion links on the right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid?noredirect=1&lq=1
http://codepen.io/dalgard/pen/Dbnus

But thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: That hardly qualifies as a solution, since it does not keep the `space-between` justify rule of your `flexbox` elements, which seemed to have been what you were asking for. It's pretty much like saying the guillotine is effective in getting rid of dandruff. Which happens to be true, but defeats the purpose.