# Don't show wide gap between items when they don't fill the row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Please check this [fiddle](https://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/YVqMEm) where when you resize the window and when the cards are going down, the bottom part of the cards looks odd with more space between them. I want those bottom parts of the cards be align with the above cards.

I know this can be done easily with `display: inline-block` but I am trying to do this using flexbox i.e `display: flex`.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing `justify-content` to `justify-content: flex-start;` seems to do the trick. extra spacing can be added using `margin-bottom` and `margin-right`.

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg then there would be odd gap on right side when resizing..

Comment: Perhaps this topic helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aligning the last items in a flex container can be tricky. There are currently no built-in properties or methods in the flexbox spec for targeting the last item in a row / column.

But there are many hacks, including the use of invisible flex items and pseudo-elements to occupy space and, therefore, achieve the desired alignment.

This is all covered in the following post:

- [Targeting flex items on the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176419/targeting-flex-items-on-the-last-row)

---

However, your layout can be easily achieved with Flex Layout's sister technology, Grid Layout:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;                                                  /* 1 */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));   /* 2 */
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;                                          /* 3 */
  grid-gap: 10px;                                                 /* 4 */
}
.child {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

[**codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWxRBj)

Notes:

1. Establish block-level grid container. ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-containers))
2. Enable the grid to create as many columns as can fit on the screen (`auto-fill`). Each column can be a minimum width of 200px, and a maximum width of `1fr` (i.e., proportion of free space; similar to `flex-grow: 1`). ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#repeat-notation))
3. The grid will automatically create new rows to accommodate wrapping grid items. Each row will have a height of 200px. ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks))
4. Shorthand for `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap`. Sets a 10px "margin" around each grid item. ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#gutters))

**Browser Support for CSS Grid**

- Chrome - full support as of March 8, 2017 (version 57)
- Firefox - full support as of March 6, 2017 (version 52)
- Safari - full support as of March 26, 2017 (version 10.1)
- Edge - full support as of October 16, 2017 (version 16)
- IE11 - no support for current spec; supports obsolete version

Here's the complete picture: http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: Thanks for this knowledge :)

Comment: Looks great.. with detailed explanation. Thanks again!!