# Using flexbox, how to make the cards not grow to fill the space on the last row?

Tags: css, flexbox

How could I, by using flexbox, make all the cards the same size, and on the second row, if there aren't enough cards to fill the row, then align the cards to the left, and leave empty space on the right? At the moment, the cards grow to fill the space, on the second row.

[image: Dummy data - flexbox example]

Here is my CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.card {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Please include HTML, and ideally a working demo, thanks

Comment: see my answer it will be help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44420542/4824088

Comment: Also possible dupllicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid/44420542#44420542

Comment: @Paulie_D, please note the first question you indicated as answer asks for aligning items on last row *"to grid"* while this question only wants them algined to left, irrespective of their width (there's no grid). I added my answer there as well, since it gets pointed to a lot.