# CSS tables without nested divs?

Tags: html, css, css-tables, display

Is it possible to create grid layouts with `display: table` without nested divs?

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="article1">
 <div id="article2">
 <div id="article3">
 <div id="article4">
 <div id="article5">
 <div id="article6">
</div>
```

The result should be for example a 3x2 table. If I apply `display: table-cell` to the article divs I get them all in a row. I assume there is no possibility to create a new row after 3 divs without nesting them in HTML?

Comment: No. That can't be done with that markup.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use flexbox model instead, like this:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container>div {
  width: 33.3%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Check the example [here](https://codepen.io/fox_hover/pen/a8d95030ff6751d075e3fac69b2d6656) - on the codepen.

So no need in additional div tags

Comment: @0711master why not to use floats and width: 33.3% ? It's better than tables too. It's supported since IE6

Comment: Because floats are not made for layouting like this and the advantage of table cell is that they all have the same height and adapt if one is getting higher...

Comment: @0711master Flexbox is supported in [all current versions of all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). Make it degrade gracefully for the random IE6 user and be done with it.

Comment: Yes, but the problem with flexbox is also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid

Comment: @0711master You're not using Flexbox because of a *solvable* problem? Implement one of the *twenty five* answers on that page.

Comment: Officially it's not solvable, only through hacks. Also most of the solutions use flex-start und not space-between as the question creator requires. The only good solution with :after is putting extra content, but also if the the last row has the full amount of elements - this causes the divs to move to the left.