# How to build a CSS flex-grid, with space between the child-elements, but without an empty place?

Tags: css, flexbox

This snippet demonstrates the problem:

```css
.flex-cont{
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between; 
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
.child {
  flex-basis: 30%; 
  height: 70px; 
  margin-bottom: 25px; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  background-color: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-cont">
  <div class="child one"></div>
  <div class="child one"></div>
  <div class="child one"></div>
  <div class="child one"></div>
  <div class="child one"></div>
</div>
```

I want the available space to spread in between the child elements. But when there is a row with less elements than columns, I want them to display one after the other, without an empty spot. Any ideas on how to solve this using CSS?

Comment: i was about to answer this when closed .. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oyBrRE made the pen instead

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu  the duplicate is still buggy ;)  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rKjEEj child have a size and do not touch each others

Comment: @G-Cyr, it's not if the flex-basis is `100% / n` and you take the margin and border into account. Here's [an example](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/ERZqYX). If you think you have a better solution for this problem, post it on the initial question.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu still buggy somehow, there are suppose to be 3 on a row ?. calculation is simple. 3 box of 30% makes 90%, 10%% are left in the gaps in between. 30 + 10 is the margin-right needed for any child on second position on the row if last ;)  box-sizing maybe ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YvNmPO

Comment: @G-Cyr, this is [what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POktM.png) from the updated pen I posted. And yes, if you want extra spacing you're supposed to achieve it centering the child of your desired max-width inside the flex item. It's a known limitation of flexbox model and the question ***is*** a duplicate.

Comment: here is what your pen produces https://i.stack.imgur.com/57y1m.jpg , box-sizing fixes it ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr, by the way, I happen to agree with [@cimmanon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18744786/1891677). Flexbox is not, technically, a grid system and `flex:grid;` should be used for the above layout. See Nicolás Arévalo's answer.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu for me `::after {content:'';flex:auto;}` is not a duplicate in this case ,see my earlier  pen using your duplicate answer.  Your fork needs a fix , my fix was nth-child not calc()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172855/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-g-cyr).

Comment: How ever, Ben should have its answer anyway ;)

Comment: So, in your oppinion, [SO] should reward lack of (re)search, @G-Cyr? If you think it's not a duplicate, please vote for re-opening it. In my opinion, it's a duplicate.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, without rejecting your last comment, I have invested time to search the topic. 
Thanks to the help of everyone I found a solution I am happy with.