# Let Flexbox Tiles flow like justified text?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

**I have a flex layout for a number tiles (of fixed size. Number of tiles and container width will vary) , using:**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[image]

My tiles have a fixed size and I like the space being ditributed evenly. With the exception of the last row, that I would like to end as justified text would usually end, **with the last element(s) not being stretched to full width but rather end naturally (green square). – Any way to achieve this?**

Comment: So many duplicates...lemme look

Comment: Centering is not what I want, because space is not distributed inbetween (≠ justify), however [18744164](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid) is close (though unlike me about expanding, not fixed-size tiles…) and then [2nd highest rated solution looks pretty good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22018710/444255) .

Comment: Above solution is truly brilliant: https://codepen.io/dalgard/pen/Dbnus