# Vuetify grid of cards aligned with a divider

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make a grid of cards that hold an image and a title using Vuetify.

I have managed to make a grid with the help of a few examples and managed to make this (This is on breakpoint XL):

[image: Grid in XL breakpoint]

But the problem is that, if the screen goes smaller, the grid isn't much of a grid anymore, but rather looks like this (this is on breakpoint LG):

[image: Grid in LG breakpoint]

I'm using justification: `space-between` but if I use `start` this is the result:

[image: Grid in LG breakpoint with justify-start]

My goal is to have a grid aligned with the `v-divider` above and also is justified in the start without the awkward gap in the second row in the LG breakpoint.

Here's my code:

```html
<v-container>
    <v-row justify="space-between">
      <v-col md="6" cols="12">
        <h1>Grid</h1>
      </v-col>

      <v-col md="6" cols="12">
        <v-text-field
          outlined
          dense
          hide-details
          :placeholder="$t('search')"
          prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
          :class="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp ? 'mt-2' : ''"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <v-row justify="space-between">
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-divider></v-divider>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <v-row :justify="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown ? 'center' : 'start'">
        <v-col cols="auto" v-for="(item, index) in machines" :key="index">
          <v-hover v-slot="{ hover }">
            <v-card class="mb-4" :elevation="hover ? 5 : 2">
              <v-card-text>
                <v-img
                src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/bc87eadb-62dd-4748-bcb6-cc4f38594988"
                contain
                :width="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp ? '300' : '385'"
                height="250"
              ></v-img>
              </v-card-text>

              <v-card-actions>
                <v-btn text color="deep-orange">
                  Arthur Morgan
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-hover>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, the correct answer is: you **should not** use flexboxes from `v-col` and `v-row` classes for these purposes.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid) you can find a wide variety of answers. But most of them looks like crutches or lead to unexpected effects.

But you may use [CSS Grid Layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to fix your problem.

So change your row code to:

```js
<v-row :justify="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown ? 'center' : 'space-between'" :class="getClassByScreenSize()">
  ...
</v-row>
```

Then create some CSS classes using grid layouts ([fr unit explanation is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#the_fr_unit)):

```
.two-cols {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.three-cols {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.five-cols {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
```

And then create `getClassByScreenSize` method to put classes to your template based on current vuetify breakpoint:

```js
...
methods: {
  getClassByScreenSize() {
    if (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xlOnly) {
      return 'five-cols'
    }
    if (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.lgOnly) {
      return 'three-cols'
    }
    if (this.$vuetify.mdOnly) {
      return 'two-cols'
    }
    return ''
  }
}
```

Check this [at CodePen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/yLPVWXY).

Comment: this is amazing. I did try grids, but I didnt know how to integrate it with Vuetify `v-row` and `v-col`

Answer (score 0):

Like the second `v-row` write below condition for first `v-row`:

```
<v-row :justify="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp ? 'space-between' : 'start'">
```

hope this helped you.

Comment: Hi Kian, I tried this and it has no affect on the divider and also the first `v-row`. Either way this doesn't do anything for the grid of cards i.e. the third `v-row`