# Css grid template columns repeat with auto size

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with a dynamic amount of elements of the same size (imagine a grid-shaped image gallery where each image is of the same size).

template columns with repeat and auto-fill provides exactly what I need:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 40px);
  row-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
<div>
```

Now, I have the same component (angular) in another place but the items should have a different size, say `100px * 100px`.
So what I'm searching for is a way to express something like `repeat(auto-fill, auto);` - i want the automatically created columns to be sized according to the children.
How to do this?

I tried to use flexbox as well, but the problem is that I want `space-around` for centered layout and aligning the last line to the 'grid' [does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744164/flex-box-align-last-row-to-grid) (it will be centered if there are less items than 'columns')

To be precise: I'm searching for a modification to the css of `.container` which is does not require to set the column width in `repeat()` to the explicit 60px, such that the following snippet works "the same way" as the first one:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 40px);
  row-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.big-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big-item"></div>
  <div class="big-item"></div>
  <div class="big-item"></div>
  <div class="big-item"></div>
  <div class="big-item"></div>
  <div class="big-item"></div>
  <div class="big-item"></div>
  <div class="big-item"></div>
  <div class="big-item"></div>
  <div class="big-item"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately auto fill requires an explicit size *somewhere* so what you require does not exist outside of a javascript solution

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility that I can imagine is creating a separate class for the item size.

Use this class on the container, setting a CSS variable.

The use it in the grid template columns and the item width:

```css
.item-size {
  --width: 60px;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, var(--width));
  row-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container > * {
  width: var(--width);
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 60px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container item-size">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
<div>
```